FT232 stops being recognized after wiring ESP-01S on Ubuntu
I'm trying to use a FT232 (this specific one) to flash ESP-01S boards from an Ubuntu 22.04, plugging just the FT232 i can see it with lsusb, but after desconnecting, wiring up the ESP-01S, and connecting again it doesn't do anything, i don't see any dmesg/journalctl logs, it's like if i'd put a potato chip in the usb port, it doesn't see anything
The FT232 lights up all 3 LEDs but the ESP-01s doesn't do much, i've already tested all wires for continuity and tried with different ESPs, so i would discard that unless i was really unlucky and got a bad batch, but i have no idea how to test for that
The way i'm wiring this is, having the VCCO jumper set to 3V3:
FT232 -> ESP-01S

VCCIO -> 3V3 & EN
GND -> GND & IO0
TXD -> RX
RXD -> TX

This is my first project so don't assume i'm doing anything i don't say here right

is it being recognized again if you disconnect the ESP-01S?

Are you powering the ESP from the FTDI 3V3 source?

@jsotola yes, it does

The FT232RL chip data sheet says you can pull only up to 50mA from the internal 3.3V regulator for external purposes.
The ESP01-S module can take more than 50mA even when receiving a wireless packet.
You can't power up such high current loads from the internal FTDI regulator.

+1 these ESPs are hungry. Normally they have an additional USB to power them up during flashing - or you have to use an external supply. In my opinion it is worth investing in an FT board with several output power options; I have one for which I can choose 5 V, 3V3, 1.8V and IIRC also 1.2 V - each rail is powered via a 100 mA+ LDO.

it was this! after getting an external power supply and using that to power the ESP it now gets recognized, thanks!
